# Nhibernate - Paging and eager loading entities

Tags: nhibernate, paging, eager-loading, icriteria, fetching-strategy

I have two entities, a team and an employee.

I want get a list of employees with eager loaded teams. The list has to be paged.

```
public PagedList<Employee> GetAllEmployeesWithEagerLoadedTeams(int page, int pageSize)
{
    var criteria = GetSession()
        .CreateCriteria(typeof (Employee))
        .SetFetchMode(DomainModelHelper.GetAssociationEntityNameAsPlural(typeof (Team)),FetchMode.Eager);

    var totalCount = criteria
        .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
        .FutureValue<Int32>().Value;

    return criteria
        .SetFirstResult(page * pageSize)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
        .Future<Employee>()
        .ToPagedList(page, pageSize, totalCount);
}
```

Why this does not work?

SQL results:

```
SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM [Employee] this_;

SELECT TOP 10 y0_ FROM (SELECT count(*) as y0_, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row FROM [Employee] this_) as query WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > 10 ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reuse the criteria variable which already has the count projection and future value specified.
You need to create a new criteria for your second query.